How to get error message text which are sent by Runtime Engine

Run the following macro.
 Sub Macro1()
     MsgBox "Hello"
 End Sub


When the MsgBox pops up, press Ctrl+C keys on your keyboard.

Open a NotePad file and press Ctrl+V keys on your keyboard.

As you can see you are able to copy from MsgBox and paste into NotePad  file.

Now lets do second scenario.

Run the following macro.
 Sub Macro2()

     Dim myNumber As Integer
     myNumber = 20

     Dim yourNumber As Integer
     yourNumber = 0

     'In mathematics, a number can not be divided by zero. So the following code must throw an error.
     Dim resultNumber As Integer
     resultNumber = myNumber / yourNumber

 End Sub


When the MsgBox pops up, press Ctrl+C keys on your keyboard.

Open a NotePad file and press Ctrl+V keys on your keyboard.

As you can see you are NOT able to copy from MsgBox and paste into NotePad  file.


My question: How to copy error messages which are sent by Runtime Engine to the Windows Clipboard as I give an example in the second scenario.

Try pressing Ctrl+Insert instead.

Hi Iridium . I dont understand how to use Ctrl+Insert in my example.

Use Ctrl+Insert (instead of Ctrl+C) to copy the message, and then use Ctrl+V as normal to paste the copied message wherever you like.

Hi Iridium.  There is no difference if I use Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Insert.

Well, you can copy a message from MsgBox, but in the second case, it is not a matter of a MsgBox. It is a message sent by compiler mentioning the error number and error description.
To catch the respective data you should adapt your code in the next way (to place them in an ordinary MsgBox):
Sub Macro234()

     Dim myNumber As Integer
     myNumber = 20

     Dim yourNumber As Integer
     yourNumber = 0

     'In mathematics, a number can not be divided by zero. So the following code must throw an error.
     Dim resultNumber As Integer
     On Error Resume Next
     resultNumber = myNumber / yourNumber
     If Err.number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error number: " & Err.number & vbCrLf & " Error Description: " & Err.Description
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
 End Sub

The above code adaptation only answer your question as it has been formulated, but in the real life, with real needs, I cannot understand why the need of such an issue? Theoretically, you should use an error handling mechanism able to solve possible issues. You can use Err.Number to make the code to act in a suitable direction, according to it. For instance, If Err.Number = 5 then MsgBox "The denominator must be different of zero,,,": Exit sub.

Hi FaneDuru. Thank you very much. The code you have sent works properly. But my question is not regarding with vba code. I mean I just want to copy the error message from MsgBox by pressing Ctrl+C. So do you know a method how to copy error message from MsgBox by pressing Ctrl+C.

@Danny Coleiro You need to be more precise, I think. The above code places in a MsgBox the information which compiler placed in its own message window and it can be copied in clipbord using Ctrl + C. With that method you can even write the error number and its description directly in a text file (and open it, if necessary).  Do you mean, a Msgbox from Excel, or from another application? Do you want copying the messages sent by compiler, which are not of type MsgBox? If so, do you want copying them directly from the compiler window? I am afraid I cannot get you...

@Danny Coleiro Then, the answer is you cannot do it. The respective window does not allow such an action. I think it is possible to be read using API. But not from the same Excel session. Even when an ordinary MsgBox is sent, no any VBA code can be run. You can try it from another application supporting vba (Word, Access, CorelDRAW etc.) Probably, another Excel session. You need to create a timer with a function returning the window handler, then extract the labels text. Not so simple, but (theoretically) possible.

@DannyColeiro you may consider to include proper error handling in your code. So you can decide what should happen if an error occurs (e.g. log to a file)

Is there Err.Number=0 can be found ?

Err.Number = 0 means no error...

The message "division by zero" is not send by the compiler, it is send by the VBA runtime engine. A compiler message (eg "Variable not found", "Block If without End If") can be copied with Ctrl+C, a runtime error not (don't ask me why).
To understand the difference: A compiler error means that the syntax of your code is invalid and cannot be executed. This is known before the code is executed. A runtime error is an error that happens during the execution of the code and cannot be known in advance: A missing file, a invalid calculation (like division by 0), a numeric overflow, a not initialized object variable and so on.
The usual way to catch runtime errors is using Error Handler. This is done using On Error...-statements. When a runtime error occurs, you can use the err-object to get the error number and text.
In your case, the error is not handled by your code. The VBA runtime will display the error information in a special message box and ask you what to do (the relevant options are "End" and "Debug").
When you choose "End", the VBA process is completely stopped and the programming context is lost. All variables are reset, among them the err-object. When you choose "Debug", the execution pauses at the statement that caused the runtime error, and the programming context remains. In that case you simply can use ? err.Number, err.Description in the immediate window (and then copy the information from there).
Until you answer that question, the message box stays open (as a modal window) and there is no way to do anything within Excel or VBA until you answer the question. Only way would be to use any 3rd party tools that can read the content of all controls of all windows, but I doubt that you want to do something like that.

Hi FunThomas. Thanks to you I understand the difference between the compiler and the runtime engine. But do you know the answer of my question?

Your question is "how do I get the error text displayed from the runtime engine", and the answer is "there is no way to get it once it is displayed". Microsoft simply didn't implemented the feature to copy the text from that message box. If you need the text while developing code, use the "Debug" switch and read the err object. If you need the text within a project that is used by other users, you need to implement error handling (and again use the err object to get information about the error).
